# Using Python to Automate AutoCAD

Tags: python, automation, activex, autocad, autodesk

I'm very new to Python and AutoCAD so please bear with me. I'm trying to use Python to automate a design cycle in AutoCAD. So far I am able to add points and lines in AutoCAD via Python but I want to be able to change the linetype to a dotted line. I understand that this can be done in the command bar in AutoCAD with a few simple commands but I can't work out how to do it through Python.

```py
import array
from _ast import If
import comtypes.client
import pyautocad

#Get running instance of the AutoCAD application
acad = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")

# Document object
doc = acad.ActiveDocument

#Get the ModelSpace object
ms = doc.ModelSpace

#In ModelSpace
#Set up A4 Space
pt1 = array.array('d', [0.0, 0.0, 0])
pt2 = array.array('d', [210.0, 0.0, 0])
pt3 = array.array('d', [210.0, 297.0, 0])
pt4 = array.array('d', [0.0, 297.0, 0])
line1 = ms.AddLine(pt1, pt2)
line2 = ms.AddLine(pt2, pt3)
line3 = ms.AddLine(pt3, pt4)
line4 = ms.AddLine(pt4, pt1)

#Add central fold
pt5 = array.array('d', [105.0, 0.0, 0])
pt6 = array.array('d', [105.0, 297.0, 0])

line5 = ms.AddLine(pt5, pt6)

print("Done.")
```

This produces an A4 sized rectangle with a solid dividing line, but I want a dotted line. Any idea where I can find some information on using Python with AutoCAD? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: pyautocad uses the AutoCAD COM/ActiveX API, you'll find the documentation from here: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=1911627

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this to change the line type of `line5`:

```py
line5.linetype = 'dot'
```

Please make sure to add (load) the line type used (i.e. DOT in this case) in the list of linetype manager.

You can change the linetype scale by:

```py
line5.linetypescale = '0.01'
```