# How to use Python to copy an AutoCAD block from one file to another

Tags: python, automation, autocad

I am trying to use python to simply copy a block from one file to another in autocad, but there is a surprisingly small amount of information on how to copy things with python and autocad from what i can find.

I can see there are libraries for autocad, but I could not find how to copy, let alone copy to another file.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Seems like this way of interacting with AutoCAD might be a good way to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513680/using-python-to-automate-autocad

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the ezdxf module if you do not mind using dxf files instead of dwg.
See this answer: [Python and ezdxf copying blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708633/python-and-ezdxf-copying-blocks)